# Why is this pandas conversion to XLSX randomly failing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

I'm currently working on the following code that takes a generated CSV file and converts it into an XLSX file. Most of the time it works, but for some reason it will fail say once every 5 or 6 times I run it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_... encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
new_headers = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', ... 'Header N']
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path,engine='xlsxwriter')
i = 0
while i < len(new_headers):
    df.columns.values[i] = new_headers[i]
    i = i + 1
df.to_excel(writer, header=True, start index=False, encoding='UTF-8')
writer.save()
```

I've considered making the following change, but I'm not confident it works after testing it -

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_... encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
new_headers = ['Header 1', 'Header 2', ... 'Header N']
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path,engine='xlsxwriter')
df.columns = new_headers
df.to_excel(writer, header=True, start index=False, encoding='UTF-8')
writer.save()
```

I've also read that adding startcol=0 and startrow=0 stops some auto-formatting from occurring which may be the source of this issue. Could that potentially be the problem, or is there something else wrong here?

Comment: what about error? Show Traceback

Comment: Figured out how to log this error to a log file now, will let you know once I get first error output